# The simplest image rotator for four images with links on the bottom

Tags: jquery, image

I have four images.  I would like them to  rotate in a loop.  Under the images is an area for the text links for each image to view the image (within the animated loop).

There are so many scripts out there, no one has exactly what I want.

Can anyone make any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Comment: Jquery is preferred.  I never thought it would be so hard to find a simple image rotator with text links on the bottom.  Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to jquery cycle (which I highly recommend), there is also InnerFade which is real stripped down: http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/

In pretty much any case though, you're going to need structured html surrounding your images. So something like this

```
<ul class="rotate-this">
    <li><img src="foo.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="bar.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="foobar.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

And you would invoke it like so:

```
$('ul.rotate-this').cycle({ // or $('ul.rotate-this').innerfade({
    option: value,
    option: value
});
```

Comment: A second vote for InnerFade. It's really slim and simple and, for my uses anyway, much more versatile than jQuery Cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the cycle plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

I've only used it for images, not images and textlinks though, but it's a start!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the cycle plug-in and utilize the [after:](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) callback to load the image's link. I did something similar on my company's website. I haven't tested this, but it should be pretty close.

```
$(#imagecontainter).cycle({ after: afterSlide });

function afterSlide( currentSlide, nextSlide, options, forwardFlag) {
    $("#yourLink").attr("href", currentSlide.attr("src"));
    $("#yourLink").text(currentSlide.attr("alt"));
}
```